ESP32 S3 Pulse Counter Skipping Steps
I am running the simple example of rottary encoder and as i can see when rottary spins fast some steps are skipped. I dont know if it is due to ESP_LOGI or i am missing something. I am using ESP-32 S3 and the rottary encoder has 600 steps per rotation.
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <driver/pulse_cnt.h>
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "driver/gpio.h"
#include "esp_log.h"
#include "esp_timer.h"
#include "esp_task_wdt.h"
#include "esp_rom_sys.h"
#include "esp_system.h"
#include "esp_err.h"
#include "sdkconfig.h"
#include "freertos/queue.h"
#include "esp_sleep.h"

static const char *TAG = "example";

#define EXAMPLE_PCNT_HIGH_LIMIT 2400
#define EXAMPLE_PCNT_LOW_LIMIT  -2400

#define EXAMPLE_EC11_GPIO_A 35
#define EXAMPLE_EC11_GPIO_B 2


#define DirPin GPIO_NUM_4
#define PulcePin GPIO_NUM_5


int direction = 0;
int PrevValue = 0;
int current_value;
SemaphoreHandle_t xBinarySemaphoreClock;

void Task1(void *pvParameters) {


    esp_rom_gpio_pad_select_gpio(DirPin);
    gpio_set_direction(DirPin, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);

    esp_rom_gpio_pad_select_gpio(PulcePin);
    gpio_set_direction(PulcePin, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);

    while (1) {
        
        if(xSemaphoreTake(xBinarySemaphoreClock, portMAX_DELAY)==pdTRUE){
            
            ESP_LOGI("SEM TAKEN", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> %d", direction);
            gpio_set_level(DirPin,direction);
            gpio_set_level(PulcePin, 1);
            esp_rom_delay_us(1000);

            gpio_set_level(PulcePin, 0);
        }
    }
   
}

void TaskRottary(void *pvParameters)
{
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "install pcnt unit");
    pcnt_unit_handle_t pcnt_unit = NULL;// INFO  I TOOK IT FROM BELO
    pcnt_unit_config_t unit_config = {
        .high_limit = EXAMPLE_PCNT_HIGH_LIMIT,
        .low_limit = EXAMPLE_PCNT_LOW_LIMIT,
    };
   
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(pcnt_new_unit(&unit_config, &pcnt_unit));

    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "set glitch filter");
    pcnt_glitch_filter_config_t filter_config = {
        .max_glitch_ns = 50,
    };
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(pcnt_unit_set_glitch_filter(pcnt_unit, &filter_config));

    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "install pcnt channels");
    pcnt_chan_config_t chan_a_config = {
        .edge_gpio_num = EXAMPLE_EC11_GPIO_A,
        .level_gpio_num = EXAMPLE_EC11_GPIO_B,
    };
    pcnt_channel_handle_t pcnt_chan_a = NULL;
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(pcnt_new_channel(pcnt_unit, &chan_a_config, &pcnt_chan_a));
    pcnt_chan_config_t chan_b_config = {
        .edge_gpio_num = EXAMPLE_EC11_GPIO_B,
        .level_gpio_num = EXAMPLE_EC11_GPIO_A,
    };
    pcnt_channel_handle_t pcnt_chan_b = NULL;
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(pcnt_new_channel(pcnt_unit, &chan_b_config, &pcnt_chan_b));

    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "set edge and level actions for pcnt channels");
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(pcnt_channel_set_edge_action(pcnt_chan_a, PCNT_CHANNEL_EDGE_ACTION_DECREASE, PCNT_CHANNEL_EDGE_ACTION_INCREASE));
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(pcnt_channel_set_level_action(pcnt_chan_a, PCNT_CHANNEL_LEVEL_ACTION_KEEP, PCNT_CHANNEL_LEVEL_ACTION_INVERSE));
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(pcnt_channel_set_edge_action(pcnt_chan_b, PCNT_CHANNEL_EDGE_ACTION_INCREASE, PCNT_CHANNEL_EDGE_ACTION_DECREASE));
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(pcnt_channel_set_level_action(pcnt_chan_b, PCNT_CHANNEL_LEVEL_ACTION_KEEP, PCNT_CHANNEL_LEVEL_ACTION_INVERSE));


    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "enable pcnt unit");
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(pcnt_unit_enable(pcnt_unit));
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "clear pcnt unit");
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(pcnt_unit_clear_count(pcnt_unit));
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "start pcnt unit");
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(pcnt_unit_start(pcnt_unit));

#if CONFIG_EXAMPLE_WAKE_UP_LIGHT_SLEEP
    // EC11 channel output high level in normal state, so we set "low level" to wake up the chip
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(gpio_wakeup_enable(EXAMPLE_EC11_GPIO_A, GPIO_INTR_LOW_LEVEL));
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_sleep_enable_gpio_wakeup());
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_light_sleep_start());
#endif

    // Report counter value
    int pulse_count = 0;

    while (1) {
            ESP_ERROR_CHECK(pcnt_unit_get_count(pcnt_unit, &pulse_count));
            if (PrevValue != pulse_count ) {
                    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Pulse count: %d", pulse_count);
                    PrevValue=pulse_count;
            }
    }
}






void app_main() {

   
    xBinarySemaphoreClock = xSemaphoreCreateBinary();
    if (xBinarySemaphoreClock == NULL) {
        ESP_LOGE("app_main", "Failed to create semaphore");
        return; // Abort if semaphore creation fails
    }
    

    // Create the task and pin it to core 1
    xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(
        Task1,            // Function that implements the task
        "BlinkTask",      // Name of the task
        4096,             // Stack size
        NULL,             // Task input parameter
        1,                // Priority of the task
        NULL,             // Task handle
        1                 // Core where the task should run (1 for core 1, 0 for core 0)
    );





    xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(  
        TaskRottary,
        "RotaryEncoder",
        4096,
        NULL,
        1,
        NULL,
        0
    );
}

Further more why i cannot use more than 5 watch_points and why they have to have the High_Limit Zero and the Low_Limit

How do you know that something is skipped and how fast is "fast" when it starts to happen? It seems to me both your tasks are looping, mostly busy-waiting and eating CPU time - don't. The pulse counter should be implemented in hardware, but its drivers might still require some resources. Also might be worth trying to raise the interrupt priority from its default value.
